# Nuxt 3: Programmatically Access /public Files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I have a project using Nuxt 3, with a lot of images in the `/public` directory (and subdirectories). Now I would like to implement a simple gallery showing all images in the directory (or specified subdirectory). Is there a way to programmatically access all files in the directory, so that I can just do something like this:

```html
<script setup>
let images = ???
</script>

<template>
  <img v-for="image in images" :key="image.path" :scr="image.path" alt="" />
</template>
```

Comment: There is no way to access the structure of a directory at runtime to my knowledge, meanwhile you can probably do that at build time and pass the data somehow to your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following using a composable

`composables/useAssets.js`

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

const folderPath = './public';
const relativeFolderPath = path.relative(process.cwd(), folderPath);

export default function () {
  const files = fs
    .readdirSync(folderPath)
    .filter((file) => file.match(/.*\.(jpg|png?)/gi));

  const filesPaths = files.map(
    (fileName) => `/_nuxt/${relativeFolderPath}/${fileName}`
  );

  return filesPaths;
}
```

`YourComponent.vue`

```html
<script setup>
  const assets = useAssets();
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="item" v-for="item in assets" :key="item" />
 </div>
</template>
```

Your basically reading all the files in the specified folder which you select by configuring `folderPath` then get the relative path of that folder from the root to append it to file paths later (`process.cwd()` gets the root project path).

after getting the matched assets and storing the array in `files`, we're using `map` to construct a new array with correct relative paths of the files in order for nuxt to read it correctly